# Golang `pions` lib example issue

Tags: go, webrtc

I've just started experimenting with WebRTC with Go and downloaded [pions/webrtc](https://github.com/pions/webrtc) library but I'am stuck with it's `data-channels` example.

As it [written in docs](https://github.com/pions/webrtc/tree/master/examples/data-channels) I opened [jsfiddle client example](http://jsfiddle.net/9tsx15mg/35/).

Then I'am running `go run main.go` command in the `/go/src/github.com/pions/webrtc/examples/data-channels` folder on my server to launch data-channel.

After that I copy `Browser base64 Session Description` from jsfiddle example and paste it into my terminal where `data-channels` go script is running and it generates `Golang base64 Session Description` code which I paste into jsfiddle example and then press `Sart session` button.

And it fails to establish connection :(

This is my jsfiddle example for client side:

[image]

And this is my server side go script:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using pion-WebRTC (I am one of the developers!)

---

WebRTC uses a technology called ICE to allow peers to talk to each other. Two peers exchange IP addresses via the SDP (the text you pasted) then they attempt to communicate by sending small UDP packets between each other. Once two IP addresses successfully communicate via ICE the rest of the WebRTC steps can continue. For you this process is failing. I don't know how/why though. Firewalls, VPNs etc... all can cause problems.

You will have to debug and check different scenarios. I would try running the examples on your local PC. If that works then maybe try between a different server. A good tool to help here also is `tcpdump` that can show if UDP packets are arriving. I usually use `tcpdump -i any udp and inbound`

---

We also recently added IPv6 support, so might be worth trying from master and see if that helps at all! Hopefully this helps, but if you are still having issues feel free to ask more questions. We are also all available via our [Slack Channel](http://gophers.slack.com/messages/pion) you can sign up here [here](https://invite.slack.golangbridge.org/) and would be more then happy to chat!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am appreciating your work! Very excited about WebRTC technology. Now I'am trying to make it work on the server side with Go. I've tried different servers, may be the issue hides somewhere else, let me find it out. But it would be great if there will be some step by step tutorial (video) for **Pions** lib examples. Also I'am looking for **uv4l** project as alternative server-side implementation. Unfortunately there is not enough info for server WebRTC implementation (c++, e.t.c.). I hope WebRTC will be more popular in the near future especially for server side.

Answer (score 0):

I met similar problem, and I solved by

> echo $BROWSER_SDP | ./main

BROWSER_SDP is the session description in your browser, main is the exe by go build main.go(you can rename exe by mv). This can make sure transfer SDP to the server, which is really important.

[The detail](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/data-channels)